# git - re-apply changes from a previous commit from same branch like a merge/rebase

Tags: git

Say I have a file `foo.cpp` tracked by git, which was added in commit `A`. Then in commit `B`, I have added a big set of changes.

Now later, on the same branch, I have made changes to `foo.cpp` again, however it was based on the version of `foo.cpp` as it was in commit `A`. I would now like to re-apply the changes to it I made it commit `B`, and resolve the arising conflicts manually as if it were a merge or a rebase. Note that commit `B` is already in the history, so my attempts to use `merge`, `rebase`, or `cherry-pick` have failed, hence this question.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add and commit what you have now. Call it C. Now diff A to B for just the file *foo.cpp* and pipe that diff into a file. Now `git apply` that file.